# Authentication Process with SwiftUI on macOS

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui, webkit

I want to authenticate my user with Spotify for a Spotify client in SwiftUI now I've come to the problem that it seems like Webkit doesn't work on macOS and now I have no clue how to authenticate my user via Safari (or some other Browser).

It would be really helpful if somebody could help me and maybe have a solution and an explanation for that solution.

Thanks.

Comment: “Webkit doesn't work on macOS” Yes, it does. Are you experiencing a certain aspect that isn’t working?

Comment: @jnpdx I don't know but I've made research an2 different sites stated that Webkit doesn't work on macOS and so if it works would you please take the time to explain it to me? That would be great (inside an answer)

Comment: I don’t know how to make an answer about an issue I don’t understand— WebKit certainly works on macOs

Comment: Well, I'm trying to set up the verification process from the Spotify Web API and I would appreciate it if you could help me set up the WebView

Comment: Search "swiftui WebView macOS" to find many results, such as https://florianschulz.info/portfolio/writing/wrapping-websites-in-webviews-using-swiftui

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the `ASWebAuthenticationSession` class. This class simplifies logging into websites by creating a private browser window for people to log into a website. By using `ASWebAuthenticationSession`, you don't have to deal with WebKit.

To use `ASWebAuthenticationSession` you must perform the following steps:

- Create a custom URL type for your app to take you back to your app when someone finishes logging in.
- Create a class for the login session that conforms to `ASWebAuthenticationPresentationContextProviding`.
- Add a presentation anchor for the login session.
- Create an instance of `ASWebAuthenticationSession`, supplying the URL of the site you want to log in, the URL to go to when the session finishes, and a completion handler with code to run when the session ends successfully.

The following article has more details on working with `ASWebAuthenticationSession`:

[Log in to Websites with ASWebAuthenticationSession](https://www.swiftdevjournal.com/log-in-to-websites-with-aswebauthenticationsession/)